# How to use LSTMs on panel data?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, panel-data

I have health claims panel data for many individuals across a few years. Each row contains a record of an individual who made some sort of medical claim, along with some information about the individual/claim, like age and diagnosis. A small sample of my data looks like:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------+-----+
| ID |   Date   |        Diag1        |       Diag2       | Diag3 | Age |
+----+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------+-----+
| A  | 12/1/19  | obesity             | hi blood pressure |       |  59 |
| A  | 12/14/20 | high blood pressure |                   |       |  59 |
| A  | 2/1/21   | High blood pressure |                   |       |  59 |
| B  | 5/1/19   | arm pain            | broken wrist      |       |  34 |
| B  | 5/6/19   | arm pain            | broken wrist      |       |  34 |
| C  | 6/6/19   | headaches           | trouble sleeping  |       |  41 |
| C  | 6/9/19   | headaches           | trouble sleeping  |       |  41 |
| C  | 7/1/20   | trouble sleeping    |                   |       |  41 |
+----+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------+-----+
```

I'm trying to use a LSTM to predict if an individual (marked by ID) will likely incur another diagnoses in the near future (say 3 months), given the current date. So for example, if today were the end of February 2021, then I'd be interested in finding people would likely make at least one visit between now and the end of May 2021.

However, I don't know if LSTMs can be adjusted on a per-subject basis. I've seen LSTMs used to predict stock prices, but those examples only had one stock to examine, whereas I have multiple IDs. Does Keras Sequential LSTMs handle this type of panel data automatically? I don't think I should drop the ID column, as the output I'm looking for should more or less give me a probability that a given person with their medical claims history will make a visit in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, LSTM should work. But keras will not handle your data automatically. You need to convert your data to a list of diagnosis:

```
input = [
  [[1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 0]],
  [[3, 4], [3, 4]],
  [[5, 6], [5, 6],[6, 0]]
]
# I used only two features (two diagnosises) for simplicity.
# You should add other features: [12/1/19, 1, 2, 0, 59]

# shift input to the left to get labels so that the next features are predicted on the every step

labels = [ 
  [[2, 0], [2, 0], [0, 0]],
  [[3, 4], [0, 0]],
  [[5, 6],[6, 0], [0, 0]]
]
```

Comment: I understand how you got your `input` variable by mapping obesity to 1, hi blood pressure to 2, etc. but I'm not getting how you get your `labels`. 

Could you also explain how this takes time into account in the model? I'd suspect that someone who has a lot of records recently might incur more claims in the near future, so I'd like to incorporate that in to the model as well.